How to find out if a third party has killed the C++ program in Linux?
I have to return exit status 140 exit status when the program is killed, but I don't know how...
I did so many searches but all I got is when a third party tries to break the program, it will send a signal to the program, then you can catch it and return the status that you want

You can only return the number of your choice if it's a signal you can catch. Install signal handlers for all signals you can catch and then exit(140);. For signals you can't catch, you're out of luck.

You can't, at least not fully. Some signals can be caught so you can do your _exit(140), but others cannot. @TedLyngmo no, you can't call exit from a signal handler. You need full signal handling in your code if you want to do that; i.e. catch the signal, inform your event loop about it, and handle it there.

140 means "signal 12" (exit with signal has exit code 128 + signal number). On x86 that's SIGUSR2 I think, according to man 7 signal. So if you install a handler for SIGUSR2 you might be able to intercept and handle this.
